# jquery display momentary dialog

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net page and when the user clicks the Save button the database is updated in code-behind. After I have saved the record I would like to display a message or dialog for a fixed number of seconds (e.g. 5) and then have it go away. Or if the user clicks it have it go away. And then just leave them on the same page where they were.

Thanks.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: look for jquery colorbox on google and you'll get what you need i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample and maybe it will help:

```
if (condition == true) {
//Widen the scope of the myTimer variable
  var myTimer;

//Open a jQuery dialog, requires the jQueryUI
//Create the dialog on the fly
  $('<div id="myDialog"></div>').html('<p>Your content was saved!</p>').dialog({
    'width' : 200,
    'height' : 100,
    'modal' : true,
    'open' : function() {
    //Set a timer which will automatically close the dialog in 5 sec
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      //Close then remove the dialog
        $('#myDialog').dialog('close').remove();
      }, 5000); //Close in 5000 ms (5 sec)
    },
    'close' : function() {
    //For extra security, clear the timer when the dialog is closed
      clearTimeout(myTimer);
    },
    'buttons' : {
      'Ok' : function() {
        $(this).dialog('close').remove();
      }
    }
    //Check out http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog for more customize options
  });
}
```

I didn't test the above code, but it *should* work, if you customize it for your needs.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: thanks, works great. Except if i am dragging or resizing and the time expires I get an error. How can I make it if any click on the dialog to just dismiss it?

Comment: I set resizable and draggable to false and that got rid of the error.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the part about the second question. see another post below.

Comment: I also get vertical and horizontal scrollbars on IE8 when the dialog is displayed.

Comment: If you are talking about the webpage it self, not the dialog, I have noticed that too. It appears that the rendering engine for IE interprets the width and height of the page overlay differently than Gecko or Webkit-based browsers do. You can do one of two things. For your webpage's CSS set either the html or body (not sure which) `overflow-y` property to `hidden`, or you can set the `modal` property of the jQuery dialog to `false`. You won't have an overlay then, but your scroll bars will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering your second question, how to make the whole dialog disappear if any part of it is clicked. Just add another jQuery block:

```
$('#myDialog').live('click', function() {
//Close the dialog
  $(this).dialog('close').remove();

//Remove the timer
  clearTimeout(myTimer);
});
```

Again, I haven't tested it, but it *should* work.

Just add the above block directly after the other, larger jQuery block I showed above.

Hope that helps,
spryno724